# Copy files from Column1 in CSV to target folder name in Column2 in CSV (Linux)

Tags: linux, csv, cp

I have a CSV with two columns.  Column 1 are full file names.  Column two are folder names.  I need to copy the file in column 1 into the folder in column 2.  Both files and folders are in the same main directory.  I have the following script:

```
IFS=','
while read OS HS
do
    cp -av $OS $HS
done < SlingManifest.csv
```

This says it's working, but when I check the folder I get a file with no name.  The contents of the file are correct, but the file has no name and only one file exists in each folder.  How can I prevent this?

Sample vim of CSV:

```
TinyHouseNation_600SqFtPowercouplesRetreat_190473_SLING.xml,./2_25_17/
BuyingTheView_RuralCasaNiagara_192555_SLING.xml,./2_26_17/
BuyingTheView_SexyHideAwayToronto_192546_SLING.xml,./2_26_17/
LifetimeOriginalMovie_LoveByThe10thDate_188563_SLING.xml,./2_27_17/
Special_10thDateGirlsNightIn_196744_SLING.xml,./2_27_17/
Special_SniperInsideTheCrosshairs_49112_SLING.xml,./2_27_17/
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to [your other question](http://superuser.com/questions/1180074/how-to-move-files-to-specific-folders-based-on-csv-entries/1180210), no? I mean I guess it's 'copy' rather than 'move', but still.

Comment: Is this a windows system or could the script have encountered a windows based editor?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the directory exists before trying to copy to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS=','
while read OS HS
do
    mkdir -p $HS
    cp -av $OS $HS
done < SlingManifest.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I used a for loop to make text files for each sub folder, then I used a new nested for loop to copy the contents of the text file into the appropriate folder.  Worked.